# Key derivation usage for deep-level data storage

Tags: encryption, key-generation

Let's say I have the following security scheme:

```
Master entity
    |
    |
    v
   Group entity-----> Child entity 1
        |     |-----> Child entity 2
        |     \-----> Child entity 3
        |
        v
      Data vault
```

The master entity contains the master key. Every time a new `Group` entity is created, a new derived key from the master key should be created and assigned to that group (provided a password for the `Group`). And every time a new `Child` entity is created, a new derived key from the `Group` should be created (provided a password for the `Child`).

- There is some data that needs to be stored in such a way that all `Child` entities of a `Group` can access it (without knowing the `Group` password)
- It must be possible to change/recover any of the `Child` passwords by the `Group` or the `Master` (without the `Child` losing access to the `Data vault` once the new key is generated)
- It must be possible to change/recover the `Group` password by the `Master` (without losing access to the `Data vault` once the new key is generated).

Is that actually possible with key derivation, and if so:

- are there any security flaws (aside from the obvious one, aka, leaked master/group keys)
- how exactly would it be done (a brief explanation would be more than enough)

Comment: In LUKS-style each actual key is wrapped by the key of the entity needing access. Upon adding an entity, the key needs to be decrypted by an existing entity and wrapped by the added entity. This way both entities can access the same key without knowing each others key. This also works in a tree; each upper entity can unwrap all of the lower keys but not the neighbors or upper keys. Unwrapping the group key will only get you access to whatever was encrypted with that key, i.e. a vault/disk image. As long as you only add a wrapped copy of the private key below the current entry, you can't go up.